# Distinct Aggregate function in Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, distinct, aggregate-functions

I have two tables - Sales(ID, Staff_Name, Sale_Date, Amount), Expense(ID, Expense_Name, Expense_Date, Amount)

The problem is to display the sum of amount for sales and expense in two columns for a given date.

The following code works in Oracle SQL:

```
select sum(distinct sales.amount),sum(distinct expense.amount) from sales,expense where sales.sale_date='06-dec-1996' and expense.expense_date='06-dec-1996';
```

But since MS Access does not support distinct inside the aggregate function, i tried this (which works):

```
SELECT Sum(Sales.amount) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Sales.amount FROM Sales);
```

But i could not get to work what i actually need. How can i do it in MS Access?

Comment: There's no join-condition in your current query, thus you CROSS JOIN all rows from `Sales` to all rows from `Expense` for that date. That's the reason why you try toi add `DISTINCT`, but this would just hide a very bad query. Gordon's approach is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subqueries:

```
select (select sum(sales.amount)
        from sales
        where sales.sale_date = '06-dec-1996'
       ),
       (select sum(expense.amount)
        from expense
        where  expense.expense_date = '06-dec-1996'
       )
from (select count(*) from sales) as s;
```

Note:

- The `from` clause is only because MS Access requires something there and doesn't support anything like `dual`.
- The date formats might need to be adjusted.
- This version is better than your version.  What if two rows had the same `sales.amount` value or the same `expense.amount` value?  Your totals would be incorrect.
- Never use commas in the `FROM` clause; *always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.